# scalaxb: ConnectException: Worker has already been shutdown

Tags: soap, netty, scalaxb

After updating my Scala SOAP client code to the most recent **scalaxb** (1.2.1) and switching to Features (instead of Eithers), I'm getting a `ConnectException: Worker has already been shutdown` when making a simple SOAP request:

```
val service = (new aw.ServicesSOAPBindings with Soap11ClientsAsync with scalaxb.DispatchHttpClientsAsync {}).service

// list providers
service.listProviders(4) onComplete { 
  case Success(respond) => 
    println(s"Respond: code ${respond.ErrorCode}, messsage: ${respond.ErrorMessage}, Providers: ${respond.Providers.size}")
    if (!respond.Providers.isEmpty)
      listKnownProviders(respond.Providers)

  case Failure(failure) => println("Failure I : " + failure.printStackTrace())
}
```

Am I missing any Netty/Dispatch configuration steps?

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.net.ConnectException: Worker has already been shutdown to https://service.xxxxxxx.com/wsdl/v4/
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyResponseFuture.abort(NettyResponseFuture.java:342)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:107)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:427)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.addListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:145)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.doConnect(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1136)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.execute(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:937)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.nextRequest(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1397)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.nextRequest(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1393)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.remotelyClosed(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1514)
    at com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyConnectListener.operationComplete(NettyConnectListener.java:95)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:427)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:418)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setFailure(DefaultChannelFuture.java:380)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientSocketPipelineSink$1.operationComplete(NioClientSocketPipelineSink.java:115)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListener(DefaultChannelFuture.java:427)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.notifyListeners(DefaultChannelFuture.java:413)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelFuture.setSuccess(DefaultChannelFuture.java:362)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$ChannelCloseFuture.setClosed(AbstractChannel.java:355)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.setClosed(AbstractChannel.java:185)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioChannel.setClosed(AbstractNioChannel.java:197)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.setClosed(NioSocketChannel.java:84)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:356)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.close(NioClientBoss.java:167)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:306)
    at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioClientBoss.run(NioClientBoss.java:42)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
    at org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Thanks in advance for any hints.

Answer (score 1):

After learning and playing more with Scala concurrency I'm able to provide an answer to my own question:

`service.listProviders(4)` returns `Future`. The root problem here is that the program terminates before the future is complete. `onComplete`is just a cool way to register a callback and doesn't block anything. To make a simple example (as this one) to work, I was supposed to block the program termination until the future completes. Some like that:

```
val futureList = service.listProviders(4) 
futureList onComplete {
   ...
}

Await.ready(futureList, 15 minutes)
```